# loaded keras model doesn't have predict method

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, dqn

In the DQN algorithm, the agent is trained successfully and the model is saved as a `.h5` file.
The agent class has a method called `load` as follows:

```
def load(self):
    new_model = load_model('dqn_model.h5')
    if self.epsilon == 0.0:
       self.update_network_parameters()
    return new_model

def update_network_parameters(self):
    self.model.set_weights(self.new_model.get_weights())
```

I try to run the evaluation step by creating the `new_model` as follows:

```
new_model = agent.load()
```

but the `new_model` doesn't have any method like `predict`.

Comment: So you can't run `new_model.predict()`. Apologies as I am unfamiliar with keras, but is load_model something from keras?

Comment: @user1558604 Yes. It's already imported from `keras.models`

Comment: How were you trying to run predict? You wouldn't run it on the `load` object, but instead the model that you loaded (`new_model`)

Comment: @user1558604 sorry for the typo. I edited that.

Comment: That seems unlikely to me given that the documentation says that `load_model` returns a `Model` instance and that `Model` instances have a predict method. Can you print the results of `dir(new_model)` and include that in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have Model imported within the class your calling `agent.load` from.

```
from keras.models import Model
```

Also, for me personally, `model.predict` doesn't show up within Intellisense so make sure that code actually doesn't compile when you run it. If so tell us what the exception error is.